# Rust Async Borrow Lifetimes

Tags: asynchronous, rust, borrow-checker, generic-constraints

I'm trying to make a helper that allows asynchronously chaining side effects, but I'm unable to get the generic bounds correct so that the compiler understands the output of the future outlives a reference used to build it.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ae782e85a528e51b456956f610af944f)

The gist of it comes down to:

```rust
struct Chain<T> {
    data: T
}
impl<T> Chain<T> {
    pub async fn chain<E, Fut, F>(self, effect: F) -> Result<T, E>
        where
            Fut: Future<Output=Result<(), E>>,
            F: FnOnce(&T) -> Fut
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

gives a compiler error of

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:39:32
   |
39 |     let r = chain.chain(|this| this.good("bar")).await;
   |                          ----- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                          |   |
   |                          |   return type of closure `impl Future` contains a lifetime `'2`
   |                          has type `&'1 MyData`
```

If we fix up `chain` so that it can infer that the reference is available for the same lifetime as the future:

```rust
impl<T> Chain<T> {
    pub async fn chain<'a, E, Fut, F>(self, effect: F) -> Result<T, E>
        where
            T: 'a, 
            Fut: 'a + Future<Output=Result<(), E>>,
            F: FnOnce(&'a T) -> Fut
    {
        effect(&self.data).await?;
        Ok(self.data)
    }
}
```

We get a new compiler error about moving `self.data` while it's still borrowed.

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `self.data` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:30:12
   |
23 |     pub async fn chain<'a, E, Fut, F>(self, effect: F) -> Result<T, E>
   |                        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
29 |         effect(&self.data).await?;
   |         ------------------
   |         |      |
   |         |      borrow of `self.data` occurs here
   |         argument requires that `self.data` is borrowed for `'a`
30 |         Ok(self.data)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^ move out of `self.data` occurs here
```

I guess there's a pathological closure along the lines of `|this| futures::future::ready(Err(this))` that would cause an early return with the borrow still "alive".

#### Question

How can we get `chain` to work?  My normal lifetime trick of block-scoping doesn't seem to help.  Is there a set of `where` constraints that can be added to prove that the borrow and then eventual move are on disjoint lifetimes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular situation is one where the current constraint syntax and lack of higher-kinded types does not let you express what you want.

You can use a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), the `for<'a>` syntax, to introduce an intermediate generic lifetime parameter `'a` within a `where` clause to dictate that the constraint must be valid for *any* lifetime. This is necessary here and the reason your first fix didn't work was because `'a` as a generic on `chain` meant that the lifetime was determined *by the caller*, however, lifetime of `self` is by construction less than any lifetime that could be picked by the caller. So the slightly more correct syntax (and identical to the de-sugared original code) would be:

```
pub async fn chain<E, Fut, F>(self, effect: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where
        Fut: Future<Output = Result<(), E>>,
        F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a T) -> Fut
{
    ...
```

But this doesn't help at all, since there is still no association between `Fut` and `'a`. There's unfortunately no way to use the same `for<'a>` across multiple constraints. You could try using `impl Trait` to define it all at once, but that isn't supported:

```
pub async fn chain<E, F>(self, effect: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a T) -> (impl Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + 'a)
{
    ...
```

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and method return types
  --> src/lib.rs:35:44
   |
35 |         where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a T) -> (impl Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + 'a)
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There will hopefully be better support for higher-kinded types in the future. This particular case *might* have a solution on nightly by using the *almost-complete* [generic associated types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) feature, but I haven't yet found it.

So the only real fix then is to use a named type as the return value, which really only leaves us with trait objects:

```
use std::pin::Pin;
use futures::future::FutureExt;

pub async fn chain<E, F>(self, effect: F) -> Result<T, E>
    where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a T) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<(), E>> + 'a>>
{
    ...

let r = chain.chain(|this| this.good("bar").boxed()).await;
```

---

As a side note, your `bad` case still does not compile and indeed cannot work, since you'd be returning a reference to a local value.

Comment: Hey @kmdreko - thanks for the reply!  This line "lifetime of self is by construction less than any lifetime that could be picked by the caller" was great and I learned something new.

I got inspiration from another part:  "There's unfortunately no way to use the same for<'a> across multiple constraints."   Maybe it would be possible to nest multiple restrictions into a single constraint via a helper trait?  

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=789c44ae54215c269aa4a09dcb001f17)

Any insights on why the helper isn't generic enough?

Comment: @moatra your persistence has paid off! Your attempt revealed this issue: [HRTBs: "implementation is not general enough", but it is](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70263) which documents that generic closure lifetimes don't really work if its not immediately deduced to a `Fn*` type (closure -> `FnHelper` -> `FnOnce`) but it does work with functions! [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6187255aa5814b8d10216f72f807f0da) works and compiles. I'll have to rethink and revise my answer with this in mind.

Comment: Nice find!  It's nice to know that it can be done with properly annotated functions, but it sure would be nice to be able to use closures and let the compiler handle the inferencing.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement [future.then()](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.26/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.then)

If you are aware of that and you are doing it as an exercise, you probably should design it in a way that the *effect* method returns values, and use these values to return from *chain* method. That way you enforce proper order of operations. As far as I understand your design, you do not benefit from awaiting on *effect* inside the *chain* method, since as your *skip* function is also async and will return future (the actual return type of *chain* method is  Future<Output=Result<T, E>>, since async works that way: it wraps your explicit return type in future).

So there is no point in awaiting on the *effect* inside the *chain*, you still have to *await* it whenever you use it - and nothing will happen until you actually await for it outside of the *chain* - futures are lazy that way.

TL;DR I would arange your *effect* methods to return values and arrange *chain* to just return these values

Comment: Hey @Scherzo - thanks for the help!  The `future.then()` link is a good reminder that I need to go familiarize myself with that library.  

In the general case, your point about it generally unhelpful to await a future inside the chain rings true.  In my particular case, I need to persist the results of a calculation and return those same results back to the client.  However, if the persistence fails, I need to return an error response to the client instead.

I'll take a dive through those docs and see if anything jumps out at me, but I'm enjoying this exercise.

Comment: @moatra The result of your proposed ".await?" unwraps a value, but it is also a result. Why? Because async functions (like the effect you call) return a result of a value you provide as return type: hence what effect really does is it returns type Result<Result<T,E2,>,E1>. If you say you want to send error regarding failed computations, you still need to handle that - currently you only handle the potential errors of await/async itself.

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8716658657b115a33d5ab5ada6f7271d) showing what I'm trying to accomplish.   See comments at lines 32 and 168